# How to make expect nested in the bash script properly?

Tags: bash, shell, expect, heredoc, quoting

Here is the expect file which can run succesfully.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect  -f
set host vps_ip
set user test
set loginpwd  passwd
set adminpwd  passwd
set timeout 300
set prompt "#|>|\\\$"    
spawn scp  /home/wpdatabase_backup.sql   $user@$host:/tmp
expect -nocase  "password:"
send "$loginpwd\r"
expect eof
spawn  ssh  $user@$host
expect -nocase "password:"
send "$loginpwd\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "su\r"
expect  "assword:"
send "$adminpwd\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "mysql -u root -pxxxx wpdatabase < /tmp/wpdatabase_backup.sql\r"
expect eof
```

Here is the bash file:

```
mysqlword="xxxx"
mysqldump -u root -p$mysqlword wpdatabase > /home/wpdatabase_backup.sql
```

Now i want to make the expect file nested in the bash file because the bash file is more complicated than expect file ,most lines in the bash file were omitted.

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
mysqlword="xxxx"
mysqldump -u root -p$mysqlword wpdatabase > /home/wpdatabase_backup.sql    
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
set host vps_ip
set user test
set loginpwd  passwd
set adminpwd  passwd
set timeout 300
set prompt "#|>|\\\$"

spawn scp  /home/wpdatabase_backup.sql   $user@$host:/tmp
expect -nocase  "password:"
send "$loginpwd\r"
expect eof
spawn  ssh  $user@$host
expect -nocase "password:"
send "$loginpwd\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "su\r"
expect  "assword:"
send "$adminpwd\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "mysql -u root -pxxxx wpdatabase < /tmp/wpdatabase_backup.sql\r"
expect eof
<<EOD
```

An error occur :
spawn scp /home/wpdatabase_backup.sql @:/tmp
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
lost connection
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "\r""

Quote the terminator:

```
cat<<'EOD'
set host vps_ip
set user test
spawn scp  /home/wpdatabase_backup.sql   $user@$host:/tmp
EOD
```

Result:

```
set host vps_ip
set user test
spawn scp  /home/wpdatabase_backup.sql   $user@$host:/tmp
```

But how to make the output of result run in bash?

```
/usr/bin/expect  <<cat<<'EOD'
set host vps_ip
set user test
spawn scp  /home/wpdatabase_backup.sql   $user@$host:/tmp
EOD
```

The code can't run!

Comment: Since this is bash shouldn't you set the variables like this  `user=test` and `host=vps_ip` instead of using the expect syntax?

Comment: In my demonstration you forgot to delete the `/usr/bin/expect <<`: the line with cat must read `cat<<'EOD'`. As for your bash script, it should read `/usr/bin/expect << 'EOD'` (without the cat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in a here-document with an unquoted terminator like `EOD`, parameter substitution is performed by the shell. You can see that if you replace `/usr/bin/expect` with `cat`:

```
$ cat<<EOD
set host vps_ip
set user test
spawn scp  /home/wpdatabase_backup.sql   $user@$host:/tmp
EOD
```

Result:

```
set host vps_ip
set user test
spawn scp  /home/wpdatabase_backup.sql   @:/tmp
```

So, how to avoid parameter substitution? Quote the terminator:

```
$ cat<<'EOD'
set host vps_ip
set user test
spawn scp  /home/wpdatabase_backup.sql   $user@$host:/tmp
EOD
```

Result:

```
set host vps_ip
set user test
spawn scp  /home/wpdatabase_backup.sql   $user@$host:/tmp
```

Comment: The result will be displayed on the sceen, how to make the content displayed on the screen to run in expect environment?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature All you need to change is to quote the terminator: `/usr/bin/expect << 'EOD'`. It's a one line change. My example using cat is only **to make visible** what substitutions the shell makes to the here-document fed to a command.